# How can i find available dialogs ,controls of an application in pywinauto?

Tags: python, windows, pywinauto

I am using pywinauto in windows 7 and I am searching for a way to find the available dialogs and controls of an application.The following is an example:

```
from pywinauto import application
import time

app=application.Application()
app.connect_(title_re = ".*Notepad", class_name = "Notepad")
```

You can start or connect to an application with pywinauto.But I don't know how can I find whats available in notepad.Any ideas ? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

This is working for me. 
Source: http://pywinauto.github.io/docs/getting_started.html

```
from pywinauto import application

app = application.Application.Start("Notepad.exe")
app.Notepad.print_control_identifiers()
app.Notepad.MenuSelect("Edit->Replace")
app.Replace.print_control_identifiers()
```

Or you can use [Swapy](https://code.google.com/p/swapy/) to see all controls and class names

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can find what available in app by executing print_control_identifiers(). Try this code :

```
app.print_control_identifiers()
```

Comment: that doesn't work.

`TypeError: '_DynamicAttributes' object is not callable`